# How to reload page without _layout query string parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, url, query-string

Page url is in form

```
http://example.com/myapp?param1=1&otherparam=somevalue1&_layout=somevalue2&someother=something
```

Page contains button "reset layout" which invokes javascript code:

```
        window.location.reload();
```

How to reload page without `_layout=somevalue2` parameter ?
Is it possible/reasonable to use javascript for this ?
This is ASP.NET MVC3 application. If javascript not reasonable, how to call server side controller for this ?

jquery and Bootstrap 3 are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression and remove all instance of `_layout`

```
  location.href=location.href.replace(/&?_layout=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i, "");
```